# Pyspark 2.7 Set StringType columns in a dataframe to 'null' when value is ""

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame called `good_df` that has mixed types of columns. I'm trying to set any empty values to `'null'` for columns of `StringType`. I would think the code below would work, but it's not.

```
self.good_df = self.good_df.select([when((col(c)=='') & (isinstance(self.good_df.schema[c].dataType, StringType)),'null').otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) for c in self.good_df.columns])
```

I'm looking at the error message and it's not giving me much in the way of clues:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in
>  File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 116, in
> _ njc = getattr(self._jc, name)(jc) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in
> **call** answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in
> deco return f(*a, **kw) File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in
> get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name, value)) Py4JError: An
> error occurred while calling o792.and. Trace: py4j.Py4JException:
> Method and([class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
> at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274) at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you got:

> py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.Boolean]) does not
> exist

This means you're trying to apply `AND` operator between a `Column` expression and a literal `Boolean` value.

You need change this part:

```py
(isinstance(self.good_df.schema[c].dataType, StringType))
```

to

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

lit(isinstance(self.good_df.schema[c].dataType, StringType))
```

---

That said, actually you can move the condition to check the column type into the python list-comprehension directly:

```
self.good_df = self.good_df.select(*[
    when((col(c) == ''), 'null').otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) if t == "string" else col(c)
    for c, t in self.good_df.dtypes
])
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much! The last snippet worked like a charm. You are awesome!